# developing a bot to use as gtalk contact with java

Tags: bots, google-talk

I want to develop a bot who can chat from gtalk and I have some experience with java.
I don't want to use the bot for IA purpose.
I want to use the bot to emulate a console like xterm.

**Edit:**
Ok: the question is "Any leads on how to develop it?"
thanks for the awnsers.

Comment: When you say "emulate a console, like xterm" that means you want shell access to a given box, via instant messaging?

Answer (score 4):

Google Talk uses XMPP. You could look into using [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to host your bot as [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine) application. It has built in support for receiving and sending XMPP messages.